# isdouble(), issingle(), ..., functions missing in Matlab2015a

Tags: matlab

When I try:

```
>>isdouble(1)
```

I just get the error

```
Undefined function or variable 'isdouble'.
```

It is the same for the other is* functions. But these are standard functions in Matlab and I even find them when I use the `help` or `doc` functions:

```
>>help isdouble
isdouble - Determine whether input is double-precision data type

This MATLAB function returns 1 when the DataType property of fi object a is
double, and 0 otherwise.
...
```

So does anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal, since there are no built-in functions `isdouble()`, `issingle()` etc. in the default MATLAB installation. If you want to test the class of a value/handle, use the `isa()` built-in, like in:

```
isa(1, 'double');
isa('abc', 'char');
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see this :-)

Comment: @Naveh No worries, is not like *only I* know the answer. :-)

Comment: Your right, thanks. What confused me is that I have the signal processing toolbox and that also includes the function isdouble(), which is why the help-function worked. However, the signal processing version only works for pre-defined filters so I got an error.

Answer (score 8):

These functions are a part of the [Fixed-Point Designer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/index.html) toolbox, which you might not have. You should use the [`isa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isa.html) function instead:

```
isa(1, 'double');
```